# Using Sanctum with Laravel Spark conflict

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-spark, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

**My setup**

- Laravel 8
- Laravel Spark Mollie

I'm constantly hitting a brick wall when calling API requests with Spark & Sanctum. I've installed Sanctum with no problem and migrated.

I've added `use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;` to `app/Models/User.php` and added `use HasApiTokens;` to the class.

**My Api.php route**

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'
], function () {
    Route::get('categories', [\App\Http\Controllers\categories::class, 'fetchCategories']);
});
```

When I call the Api I get this error

```
ErrorException
Declaration of Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens::tokenCan(string $ability) should be compatible with Laravel\Spark\User::tokenCan($ability)
```

I've tried changing `use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;` to `Laravel\Spark\HasApiTokens` on User.php. The error goes away, but whenever I try calling the Api, it returns me back to the login homepage.

Any ideas? As the Spark documentation doesn't really explain how Sanctum or Api protection work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your main User class extends the User class from the vendor Spark library. This User model uses the trait named `HasApiTokens` which is not the same as Sanctum

Since you don't want to change the file from the vendor directory, one fix I found was to copy the original SparkUser model class from the vendor and create a new one like this and remove the trait `HasApiTokens` since you don't want to use it anymore.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Users;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Laravel\Spark\Billable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class SparkUser extends Authenticatable
{
    use Billable, Notifiable; // HasApiTokens was removed from the original SparkUser class

/**
 * Get the profile photo URL attribute.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $value
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getPhotoUrlAttribute($value)
{
    return empty($value) ? 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.md5(Str::lower($this->email)).'.jpg?s=200&d=mm' : url($value);
}

/**
 * Make the team user visible for the current user.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function shouldHaveSelfVisibility()
{
    return $this->makeVisible([
        'uses_two_factor_auth',
        'country_code',
        'phone',
        'card_brand',
        'card_last_four',
        'card_country',
        'billing_address',
        'billing_address_line_2',
        'billing_city',
        'billing_state',
        'billing_zip',
        'billing_country',
        'extra_billing_information'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Convert the model instance to an array.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray()
{
    $array = parent::toArray();

    if (! in_array('tax_rate', $this->hidden)) {
        $array['tax_rate'] = $this->taxPercentage();
    }

    return $array;
}
```

}

And now all I had to change was my original User class model to use this new model like this and add the trait HasApiTokens from Sanctum!

```
use App\Models\SparkUser; // Modified from the original in the vendor folder
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends SparkUser
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    
    ...
}
```